# Simple Boost TCP Server, example from the book "C++ Crash Course"

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm trying to understand the thing with `std::enable_shared_from_this` in case of TCP connections and I see it like when first connection is accepted in the `serve` func, object of the class `Session` is created and later invocations just create `shared_ptr` to the same object isn't it? If I get it well, I'm not sure is it completely correct to move everytime socket in `serve`? The below example is like original one from the book besides `connections` int I've added:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
int connections{};

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    explicit Session(ip::tcp::socket socket) : socket{ std::move(socket) } {}
    void read() {
        async_read_until(socket, dynamic_buffer(message), '\n',
        [self=shared_from_this()] (boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t length) {
            if(ec || self->message == "\n") {
            std::cout<<"Ended connection as endline was sent\n" ;
            return;
            }
            boost::algorithm::to_upper(self->message);
            self->write();
        });
    }
    void write() {
        async_write(socket, buffer(message),
        [self=shared_from_this()] (boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t length) {
            if(ec) return;
            self->message.clear();
            self->read();
        });
    }
    private:
    ip::tcp::socket socket;
    std::string message;
};

void serve(ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor) {
    acceptor.async_accept([&acceptor](boost::system::error_code ec,
    ip::tcp::socket socket) {
        serve(acceptor);
        if (ec) return;
        auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket));
        std::cout<<"Connection established no "<<++connections<<"\n";
        session->read();
    });
}

int main(){
    try{
        io_context io_context;
        ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor{ io_context,
        ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 1895)};
        
        serve(acceptor);
        io_context.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm not sure is it completely correct to move everytime socket in serve?` You cannot copy a socket, it _has_ to be moved.

Comment: @tkausl, that's is understable, sure, but (if I'm right) if all `shared_ptr's` point to the same object why to invoke every time constructor and moving the socket again and again?

Comment: You sure you want to take a course in how to make C++ crash?

Comment: @user4581301 I hope to not do this. I was a little bit confused as I thought `shared_ptr` goal is mainly to share and maintain 1x object, but in this case I see my question was inappropriate. Besides I thought, what comes from the above, this example is a nice way to handle all connections with only 1x object, but it looks the purpose is different here.

Comment: Apologies for my failed attempt at humour. I was making fun of the name of the book, not adding anything useful to the conversation.

Comment: @user4581301 No prob at all, I completely find it as accurate observation of my topic :). But, going back to serious lines, are you able to answer what is the purpose of shared_ptr's here in opposite to just create new object dynamically? Is it just about we don't have to care for invoking destructors manually?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` solves a thorny problem with a notification system. You have one party receiving notifications and another delivering them. This is mediated by some sort of shared information, a "control block". The `shared _ptr` keeps the control block alive until BOTH parties are done with it, simplifying what could otherwise be a mess of competing critical sections needed to ensure safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket is moved at each invocation of `serve` because it is a *fresh* socket for a newly established connection. Note that it is passed by value and unless moved to some long-living object (`session` in this case) it will be immediately destroyed after going out of scope, ending the connection.

*"object of the class Session is created and later invocations just create shared_ptr to the same object isn't it"* - nope, each `make_shared` invocation creates a new session object - one per connection. `shared_from_this` spawns pointer to the current object.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so does it mean I'm wrong and every time this line `auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket));` creates new object?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, I've already answered this, perhaps you need to refresh the page.

Comment: This explanation is correct in the context of the question code. Note that regardless of that context, it is still valid to move from Asio sockets multiple times, as the documentation states the additional guarantee that _[Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_stream_socket(const executor_type&) constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload9.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_stream_socket.basic_stream_socket.overload9.remarks)_.